# How to disable Gradle offline mode using the command line?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to disable `gradle offline` mode for my Android project. But it seems that Android Studio v3.6 does not have any checkbox like other previous versions to control online/offline mode. What is alternatives to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible, because there only is an `--offline` switch to enable it, but there is none to disable it. Therefore, you could only enable it on-demand with that [command-line switch](http://[execution%20options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options)).

The only way I could think of, how it might work, is to use two different [init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html), with either: `startParameter.offline=true` or `startParameter.offline=false`. And then run them eg. with `./gradlew --init-script offline.gradle` or `./gradlew --init-script online.gradle`.